# How to merge two lines in a CSV file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a CSV file that has the following issue.

```
line 1:  "x","y","z","
line 2:
line 3:  "," ",": "
```

This is a single line but has been written as multiple lines. Unfortunately, I cannot ask the provider to fix it. Is there a way we can fix it?

Comment: Remove the empty lines?

Comment: I can remove the empty line (line 2) using sed but I need to merge the line 1 and 3.  This issue is occurring randomly in a large CSV file.

Comment: Aha. Are there always three physical lines per logical record? (or is the split-up irregular?) BTW are the added '\n' part of the strings and should they have been escaped?

Comment: Not always but when ever the particular string field has unescaped \n or whatever, I see three lines in the CSV file. Unfortunately, I have no access to the providers code or support to give proper explanation.

Comment: You could just do a running count of the `"`  :  when odd: suppress the `\n`. I don't know if this can be done in sed, though...

Answer (score 0):

Read the file. Go trough every line and append your output to a variable. Then you have all lines after each other.

```
$output = '';

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $output .= $line;
}
```

to read the csv file you can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). If `line 1:` is part of your csv file then split your output on the `:` and use the second part.

Comment: Sorry. Line 1: is not a part of the file, included it to explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A small C program that counts the `"` and suppresses the `\n` if this count is odd. I doubt if this could be done in sed in fewer lines ...

---

```
/***
Usage ./a.out <the_file.csv > the_file.out
**/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int ch, state;

for(state=0; ;) {
        ch= getc(stdin);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        if (ch == '"') state++;
        if (ch == '\n') {if (state %2) continue; else state=0; }
        putc(ch, stdout);
        }
if (state %2) {putc('"', stdout);
return 0;
}
```

---

Note: this will of course fail if there are escaped quotes (`\"`) in the input file.